# Issue using JavaScript variable as jQuery selector -- unrecognized expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, jquery-selectors, undo

I'm trying to use JavaScript variables as jQuery selectors to change the fill of an SVG path (really, to "undo" the most recent change made to them). I'm able to correctly access the last path that was modified, and the "color" it was filled with, and I've double checked this with `console.log()` statements.

They are:

```
  var path = Object.keys(allChanges[0]).shift();

  var oldFill = Object.keys(allChanges[0]).map(function(key){
    return allChanges[0][key];
  }).shift();
```

"path" and "oldFill" are what they are supposed to be. I'm trying to use them as jQuery selectors here:

```
$("'#"+path+"'").css('fill', "'"+oldFill+"'");
```

But I get the error message saying

> "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: '#node27'" <-- #node27 is the path I happened to be targeting.

They all have id's in my svg element.

Does anyone know where I've gone wrong here?! I've looked at this a million times!

Comment: don't you have too many quotes? the jquery selector is a string but you put quotes ' in this string

Answer (score 3):

You have a problem with apostrophes. You will have to update this

```
$("'#"+path+"'").css('fill', "'"+oldFill+"'");
```

with this

```
$("#"+path).css('fill', oldFill);
```

Comment: Ah, that worked! But why don't you need the quotes?? If I were writing this out by hand, I would need quotes around the selector and oldFill....do they get inserted automatically somehow??

Comment: You were basically double-quoting. You don't need both quotes and apostrophes. '#node27' or "#node27" but not " '#node27 ' "

Comment: `"#"` and `path` are both already strings. By putting the extra apostrophes in there, you were doing `$("'#foo'")`, not `$("#foo")`.

Answer (score 1):

You're just running into issues with your quotes. Your variables are already strings, so you don't need to quote them.

try this:

```
$("#" + path).css('fill', oldFill);
```

Comment: Oh! I didn't realize the variables were already strings. When I console logged them, it didn't look like they were, so I thought I needed the quotes.